# How to migrate existing Git-p4 repo to LFS

Tags: bitbucket, perforce, git-lfs, bfg-repo-cleaner

For this moment I have a `Git` repo that synced to the main `p4` depot and works fine.
But its size is far more than 4Gb. And we need to move it to **BitBucket**, where 2Gb is the maximum limit.
What I want to achieve:

1. Put 1 folder and 1 file extension under LFS.
2. Migrate repo to the **BitBucket**.
3. Make it sync both ways with p4 depot.

Assumption for point 1 is to use [BFG Repo cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/). Is it suitable for folders?
Is it possible to achieve point 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Assumption for point 1 is to use BFG Repo cleaner.

According to [recent edits to the Git LFS wiki](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/wiki/Tutorial#dont-use-this-use-httpsgithubcombozarogit-lfs-migrate-instead), BFG is not currently the preferred tool for this migration, you want [bozaro:git-lfs-migrate](https://github.com/bozaro/git-lfs-migrate).  That is likely due to limitations in the BFG support for this migration, which include multi-glob support etc.

> Is it suitable for folders?

Yes but perhaps not in the way you hope, hence git-lfs-migrate.  BFG [cannot process qualified/absolute paths](https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/issues/12), only paths by relative-name.

> Make it sync both ways with p4 depot.

I think so, see https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/01/work-with-git-and-perforce/ .

Comment: I ended up with similar solutions you shared.
BFG cleaner BTW supports LFS transition now. But now the problem is: when somebody modifies LFS file in p4, its' binary changes (but in Git there is instead a hash-value). After that Git-p4 rebase tool goes nuts and spoils the last Git commit with kinda combined history.

Comment: Any update on how to perform git p4 rebase after you have used git lfs migrate on the history? Is there a way to skip through all the rebase errors with git rebase --skip since there are thousands of commits to do this for?